# how to create a mapping app in C#

Tags: c#, google-maps, openstreetmap

I want to create an app in C# that can display a map of a city (Belfast, Northern Ireland in this case) and overlay on top of the map the routes of the local bus service, Translink. This would work by the user entering into a search box a departure and destination location, clicking an "execute button, resulting in the route appearing on the map. I would likely use of either Google Maps or the OpenStreetMaps system to display said maps. If possible I would also like to track the actual busses themselves in real-time, either through GPS or estimation based on the timetable and average bus speed. All of this I would like to do in C#.

I would like to ask if it is possible to make this in C#. It is the programming language I am most familiar with. I would greatly appreciate it if I could be directed to any guides or examples of such systems, especially home-grown ones. The last objective may be too specific so I wouldn't mind being pointed to examples without that feature, but I would be thankful if I could. Also, if there are examples, but they are not C# based, I wouldn't mind it too. It would just be preferable if if it could be based in C# or at least within Visual Studio or Java Eclipse.

Thank you.

Comment: So from a maths point of view you will need to look into calculating shortest paths/routes algorithms and there are some really "famous" ones. Then you'll need to work on overlaying this information with the bus information. Finally this will need to be printed out on a display. Most mapping frameworks will have detailed description of the images they show so you can accurately place lines over the top. Or they will have an api for placing lines in there

Comment: Would there be any tutorials, guides, examples that you know of those? I have never made a program like this before so have a starting point would be helpful.

Comment: Strictly speaking this isn't a question for stack overflow, I would take the points I have given you, go do lots more research, try some stuff and come back later with more specific questions which have examples

Comment: See also https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing

Comment: Did you already take a look at OsmSharp (http://www.osmsharp.com/, https://github.com/OsmSharp/core)?

Comment: Ok, since the last time I was here, I have been able to make the program display a map via the Gmap plugin, and display custom made routes on top of roads using large numbers of longitude and latitude co-ordinates for each route. Now want I want to do is to show a marker icon on the route, but it needs to positioned on a point of the route depending on the time. Say if you are logging into the program at 2pm, the marker should be at the start of the route, but if you leave and return at 3, it should be halfway along. Anywhere that shows how this could be done?

Comment: Hi Ross, we worked over the past weeks on getting recorded gpx files imported and having the recorded positions displayed as a moving marker using the actual time-spans from the data. You can keep extending this to add additional routes and display features as you have time.  I think you can mark this as answered.